# Writing a copy constructor with singly linked lists?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, singly-linked-list

I'm writing a copy constructor that copies for example S to R; Set R(S);. S is a sorted singly linked list containing some ints (with a dummy node in the beginning).

```
Set::Set (const Set &source)
{

    Node* sourceNode = source.head->next;
    head = new Node(0, nullptr);
    Node* nodeHead = source.head->next;
    Node* p;


    if (!sourceNode) {
        std::cout << "Empty !" << endl;
    }
    else{
    while (nodeHead) {
        for (p=sourceNode; p->next; p=p->next) {
            ;
        }
        head->next = new Node(nodeHead->value,nullptr);
        head = head->next;

        nodeHead = nodeHead->next;

        }
    }
}
```

Right now it crashes and if i remove head = head->next; it will set S to { 5 }.

This is the constructor:

```
class Node
{
    public:
       Node (int, Node*);

    private:
       int value;
       Node* next;
};
```

Why doesn't this work? This is my first experience with pointers so keep that in mind please.

Comment: How does that `for` loop terminate?  Any chance you could rewrite it to be more, shall we say, "best practice?"  Instead of relying on some obscure "this terminates because it eventually hits a zero" metaphor?

Comment: Do you have a function that adds to the end of the list?  If you do, why not use it instead of rewriting the code again in the copy constructor?  If you did that, then the copy constructor is a very simple loop without all of the pointer manipulations.  If you don't have a function that adds to the end of the list (why would you not?), then create one.  Once you do that, the copy constructor is easy.

Comment: You'll need to have `head` stay the same, while your copy is built with the help of another pointer. I recommend debugging using pen and paper when working with pointer-based structures. (What's up with the loop over `p`?)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have a function that adds to the end of the linked list.  The copy constructor in this case would be very simple:

```
Set::Set (const Set &source) : head(0)
{
    Node* sourceNode = source.head;
    while (sourceNode != NULL )
    {
       addToList(sourceNode->value);
       sourceNode = sourceNode->next;
    }
}
```

The `addToList` would be the function that adds a node to the back of the list.  All the copy constructor has to do is start off with an empty list, and in a loop, add items from the `source` list until the number of items in the `source` list is exhausted.  This method, given that the `addToList` function is coded correctly, is guaranteed to work, and avoids code duplication.

This is the easiest way to implement the copy constructor.  If you have no function that adds to the back of the list, now would be the good time to add it since you will need to to have such a function in any event.

Comment: Sorry but making something as simple as copying a linked list have quadratic behavior makes me shudder. Particularly since the code you avoid writing there isn't longer than the function call in the first place!

Comment: If there is a node in `Set` that is always denoted as the back node, then this is not quadratic.

Comment: In which case your implementation isn't going to work, because you don't set the endnode in the copy constructor, so it'll be a garbage value - good save though ;) Realistically a singly linked list doesn't have an end node though, because that just unnecessarily complicates the whole thing and makes an efficient immutable implementation impossible.

Comment: `In which case your implementation isn't going to work,`  As I said in the comment, "*if* there is a node in `Set`...".

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code

```
LinkList(LinkList const & temp)       // Copy constructor
{                                                                                                           
    this->head = 0;               // calling list head
    Node* tempHead = temp.head;  /*For temprory store of head of link list*/
    while (tempHead != 0)
    {
        this->insertAtEnd(tempHead->data);
        tempHead = tempHead->next;
    }
}

void insertAtEnd(int val)  
{
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->data = val;
    temp->next = 0;
    Node* curr = this->head;
    if (curr != 0)
    {
        while (curr->next != 0)
        {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        this->head = temp;
    }
}
```